# Put modal values in textarea in hidden form and load on edit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, bootstrap-modal

Basically i have 2 form in 1st form i have a textarea while 2nd form opens in modal

here is code for **form 1**.

```
    <div>
      <textarea name="dynamic-content-unit" id="dynamic-content-unit"
         class="form-control" rows="8" readonly=""></textarea>
   </div>
```

**form 2 it opens in bootstrap modal**

```
<div id="unit-of-content" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<form action="" method="POST" id="content-unit-frm" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><b>Unit Label</b>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="is_default" value="1"> Make Default
        </div><br><br>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa"></i>
                <input type="text" name="label" id="label" value="" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-icon right">
                <i class="fa"></i>
                <textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <button type="submit" id="unit-submit" class="btn green">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
  $('#unit-content').click(function() {
        new_val = $('#label').val();
        $('#dynamic-content-unit').val(new_val);
    });
   </script>
```

Here in above form i have 3 input fields

one is checkbox

two Input name

three textarea

Now i want if submit button clicked from modal all above data should go in **textarea** of form 1

Name(label) should be visible while other should be in hidden

if checkbox was checked then with Name(label) keyword default should be written

In **textarea** Name should be with a edit button if edit button click it should reload this data in modal as it was.

if 2nd time data given in modal it should go same in 2nd line and so on wile if checkbox checked for modal 2 then default should be with 2 and should remove from 1

Thanks for help

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa i tried it was putting value in text are for name but don't know how do it for edit

Comment: fine, can you show then what you have tried. Perhaps a Fiddle would be much faster for us both

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa i add jquery above in question its giving name in textbox

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: So now you want to add an edit button(I assume its not existing now) and get the value back to the `#label` input field ?

Comment: @bluemoon, I understand that, first textarea within the page is not editable directly and popup opens on edit click. So, use a div instead of textarea, then you could push data from the model form manually into different elements within div to show as you want it.

This way mapping becomes easy both ways

Comment: yes you right @NikhilNanjappa

Comment: @Chetan please explain it in answer if you can or any alternate solution

Comment: I will try to add it

Comment: @Chetan Thanks if you or any body can it for me

Comment: So it like adding each row with 3 fields information everytime model submit is done. And also each row with edit button to prefill and edit it. Is the understanding correct?

Comment: Yes You right. just label should be visible other type can be hidden and if checkbox was checked there should be default keyword with label if also checked for 2nd time in modal label should be with 2nd and remove from ist label and so on

Comment: @bluemoon, you probably should have to search for todo app examples and check how it is build. Because chances of that as answer are very low.

Answer (score 1):

After update, I recommend changing your form1 to a more `class` based structure rather than `id` based. Like so

First create a custom template(`#hidden-template`) which you need to add everytime submit is clicked.

```
<script id="hidden-template" type="text/x-custom-template">
  <div class="dynamic-content-container">
    <span class="dynamic-content-unit"></span>
    <span class="edit-icon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
  </div>
</script>

<div class="dynamic-content-container">Just for first append</div>
```

The idea is to add(append) the above template(`#hidden-template`) on every click to the **last** `.dynamic-content-container` div. Like so

```
var template = $('#hidden-template').html();

$('#unit-submit').click(function() {
  $(".dynamic-content-container").last().after(template);
  $('.dynamic-content-container').last().find(".dynamic-content-unit").text($('#label').val());
});
```

Then use JQuery to open the modal manually and copy the text from the respective div to the `#label` field. Like so

```
$(document).on('click','.edit-icon',function() {
  $('#unit-of-content').modal('show');
  $('#label').val($(this).siblings(".dynamic-content-unit").text());
});
```

> Since we adding the `.edit-icon` dynamically to the DOM, `.click` will not work, use `.on('click'` instead - **event delegation**

Comment: I asked in my Question that there can be multiple lablels one per line and every label have own data and own edit button

Comment: Your definitely not being clear in what you need. Firstly "there can be multiple lablels" is not mentioned anywhere in your question. Second what do you mean by "one per line and every label have own data" ? Your label is an `id` meaning there cannot be more than 1 element with that id(`#label`)

Comment: its mean modal will be submit multiple times so multiples label and there data

Comment: so if my understanding is right, you are planning to "append" the different values of `#label` to the textarea(form1) each time?

Comment: Hmm then your approach could be better. Let me update the code

Comment: Thanks textarea is not mandatory you can change it to div or something else

Comment: Updated the answer. Check & let me know. brb

Comment: @bluemoon - answer updated .. Check & let me know if you face any issues. Please explain the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146713/discussion-between-blue-moon-and-nikhil-nanjappa).